# How to spec out a relay correctly

Tags: relay, inductive, ratings

I have a load that I am trying to switch with a relay. The load to the relay is an autotransformer. The wiper output of the autotransformer is (2) 120:30 step down transformers with each having 150W light bulbs on the secondaries.

The legacy system had a 3A relay (field point module). I measured the steady state current to be 3.5A Irms to the autotransformer. How can the relay in the field point module support this measured current?

When trying to spec out a relay, a lot of reasonable relays only give a resistive rating, but don't I need an inductive rating for this application?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the old relay you could provide? It could be that 3A is a conservative estimate that covers all relays made, but some may manage more. Is this a product made at scale or a one off?

Comment: Specifications are always with a safety margin, you can't build a relay that is fine at 2.99A and will catastrophically fail at 3.01A

Comment: http://www.ni.com/pdf/products/us/4dio572_573.pdf

Comment: The rating is resistive for 3A at 250 VAC my assumption is that 3*250 = 750VA and working backwards 750/120 = 6.25A @120 VAC not sure if this is a viable way to prove why this relay worked with a 3.5A load. but my main question is when selecting a new relay should it have an inductive rating of greater than 3.5 A or use the resistive

Comment: The voltage and current ratings for relay and switch contacts are separate, (mostly) unrelated, maximum ratings.  For your relay the contacts can safely handle 3 Amps, regardless of voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a relay with an inductive rating. Somewhat excessive carry current often isn't an issue (depending on the design of the relay), the limitation is the contact life span. Excessive carry current causes internal heating. **Switching** excessive current causes excessive arcing and reduces the life of the contacts, or can cause welding of the contacts.

One approach is to use a relay with a heavy compressor rating and hope for the best. Something like Omron's [G7L series](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/307/en-g7l-595183.pdf). These will probably be much more expensive, larger and draw more current than your 3A relay, but the life should be much more impressive.